# Uncomprehensive Android Studio - Device emulator-5554 is offline. error - Showing only black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, flutter-doctor

After many attempts, and trying many solutions that I could find on stackoverflow or elsewhere on the internet, I was still not able to run the emulator on my computer. This is happening with this computer on both Windows and Linux boots. I am able to start the emulator but then it remains with a full black screen.
Here are some information regarding the software: Linux Ubuntu 20.04LTS and Android-studio version I am working with: 4.1.2.
About my hardware:

```
$sudo lshw -short
 
H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         GA-A75M-S2V
/0                          bus            GA-A75M-S2V
/0/0                        memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor      AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
/0/4/a                      memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/4/c                      memory         1MiB L3 cache
/0/b                        memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/26                       memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/26/0                     memory         4GiB DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/26/1                     memory         4GiB DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/26/2                     memory         DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns) [empty]
/0/26/3                     memory         DIMM 1333 MHz (0.8 ns) [empty]
/0/100                      bridge         Family 12h Processor Root Complex
/0/100/2                    bridge         Family 12h Processor Root Port
/0/100/2/0                  display        GK104 [GeForce GTX 670]
/0/100/2/0.1                multimedia     GK104 HDMI Audio Controller
/0/100/4                    bridge         Family 12h Processor Root Port
/0/100/4/0       enp2s0     network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

First I checked that the virtualization was working and it Seems to be pretty OK.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      18
Model:                           1
Model name:                      AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Stepping:                        0
CPU MHz:                         1395.339
CPU max MHz:                     3000.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        5999.33
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        4 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Not affected
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full AMD retpoline, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_
                                 good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt hw_ps
                                 tate vmmcall arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
```

Then I tried a second verification!

```
$ virt-host-validate
QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization    : PASS
```

With `flutter doctor`, it is written that the Device is offline and I have a full black screen.
Here I tried many things, graphics with hardware or software rendering, changing the RAM, changing the number of cores, changing x86 or x86_64 CPU arch, ...                                                                                               `$flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

And when doing the adb devices command:

```
$adb devices

List of devices attached 
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...
* daemon started successfully
```

I always get this error at the end: Timed out after 300 seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

I tried to do `adb server-killer` etc, doing cold boot, etc, ... nothing worked. I still got the exact same issue.
Previously I was using another computer on which everything was working fine. And I am totally struggling here.

```
$adb kill-server
$adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

And when running logcat I got a restart loop.

```
$./emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_30 -debug-init -logcat '*:v'
emulator: Android emulator version 30.3.5.0 (build_id 7033400) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Pixel_2_API_30'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86

...
[    1.453200] Run /init as init process
[    1.454227] traps: init[1] trap invalid opcode ip:59434e sp:ffa11a60 error:0 in init[462000+139000]
[    1.455590] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000004
[    1.456724] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 5.4.61-android11-0-00791-gbad091cc4bf3-ab6833933 #1
[    1.458050] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.11.1-0-g0551a4be2c-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
[    1.459787] Call Trace:
[    1.460170]  dump_stack+0x95/0xe5
[    1.460702]  panic+0x112/0x39a
[    1.461069]  do_exit+0xa99/0xb00
[    1.461455]  do_group_exit+0x89/0xa0
[    1.461887]  get_signal+0x999/0xae0
[    1.462306]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x1a/0x40
[    1.462890]  ? force_sig_info_to_task+0x111/0x120
[    1.463641]  do_signal+0x80/0x250
[    1.464039]  prepare_exit_to_usermode+0x8d/0x100
[    1.464589]  ? invalid_op+0xa/0x30
[    1.464993]  retint_user+0x8/0x8
[    1.465378] RIP: 0023:0x59434e
[    1.465743] Code: f7 83 e1 03 c1 e6 0c c1 e1 0a 09 d6 0f b6 d3 8b 5c 24 0c 09 d1 8b 55 08 09 f1 81 c9 00 01 00 00 66 0f 6e c1 8b 92 40 95 00 00 <f2> 0f 38 f1 d3 f2 0f 38 f1 d1 f2 0f 38 f1 d0 0f b7 c0 89 d6 c1 ee
[    1.468434] RSP: 002b:00000000ffa11a60 EFLAGS: 00010202
[    1.469069] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00000000f7f80a60 RCX: 0000000000018102
[    1.469901] RDX: 0000000051746398 RSI: 0000000000018000 RDI: 0000000000000018
[    1.470732] RBP: 00000000ffa11a98 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[    1.471564] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000216 R12: 0000000000000000
[    1.472394] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[    1.473344] Kernel Offset: 0x29000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[    1.475542] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default
...
```

Do you have any idea about what I could be missing exactly ? I was not able to post images.
I hope that you will be able to help me.
Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
Because I am using an old AMV processor, I needed to use an ARM based image for the emulator and not a x86 image.
I was then able to run it.
Unfortunately my processor was not powerful enough and was lagging as hell when launching the android emulator.
Had to buy a new computer.